# show random div(s) on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working on this to show/hide some div's when a link is clicked:

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/jBmH9/4/)

But now I am trying to get it so that it show a random one of those divs when the page is loaded.

I tried adding this:

```
var $reviews = $(.hider ').hide();
$reviews.eq(Math.random()*$reviews.length).show();​
```

But, it just seems to break what I've worked on before.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a syntax error right there. Make it `$('.hider').hide();` and try again.

Comment: *some div* ... be more specific... fix your code `$(.hider ').hide();` is missing an `'`

Comment: DAP!  Ok, well, that fixed the issue of it not working.

To be more specific, I am trying to get both of the divs to show randomly when the page load.  Basically I am working on sets of  galleries with a tag line for that gallery.  When the page loads, I'd like to have one of the galleries randomly show with it's tag line.

After the fix, I can get it to show a random div, but not both at the some time.  Here's the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/jBmH9/8/

Answer (score 1):

here is the code and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jBmH9/10/):

```
<div id="brother-gallery" class="hider">Brother Content</div>
<div id="mitsu-gallery" class="hidden hider">Mitsu Content</div>
<div id="taki-gallery" class="hidden hider">Taki Content</div>

<br /><br />
<div id="brother-tag" class="hider">Brother Tagline</div>
<div id="mitsu-tag" class="hidden hider">Mitsu Tagline</div>
<div id="taki-tag" class="hidden hider">Taki Tagline</div>

<br /><br />
<p><a href="#" class="control" data-field="brother">Brother Link</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="control" data-field="mitsu">Mitsu Link</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="control" data-field="taki">Taki Link</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="random">Random</a></p>

​

$('.control').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var field = $(this).data('field');
    $('.hider:visible').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $('#' + field + '-gallery, #' + field + '-tag').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});

$('.random').on('click',function(e){
    var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)%3;
    console.log(randomIndex);
    var field = $($('a').get(randomIndex)).data('field');
    $('.hider:visible').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $('#' + field + '-gallery, #' + field + '-tag').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  But I was trying to get it so it randomizes on page load.

Comment: so use the same idea as the random function, and just enclose that in $(function(){....});

Comment: I basically did this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/JmVUx/

Just need it so it doesn't show the brother stuff on the page load and then goes to the random div.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var reviews = $('.hider');
reviews.hide();
var index = Math.floor(Math.random * reviews.length);
reviews.eq(index).show();
```

You need to insure an integer value is passed to eq() call.